# php array replace

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 output from a php function as below

First output gives me some thing like this

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ('column1', 'column2', 'column3') VALUES (?,?,?)
INSERT INTO "table2" ('column1', 'column2', 'column3','column4','column5') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Other output gives

```
Array = (
1 => 'value1',
2 => 'value2',
3 => 'value3',
)

Array = (
1 => 'value1',
2 => 'value2',
3 => 'value3',
4 => 'value4',
5 => 'value5',
)
```

and now I want to do the following..
How can I replace  the "?" in the first INSERT QUERY  with values value1, value2 and value3 and same way for the second query the values in the second array.

regards

Comment: This seems like something that is automatically done by something like [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).

Comment: If it's an option, you should work with PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic solution:

```
function replaceWithArray($query, $array) {
    $n = 0;
    return preg_replace('~\?~e', '$array[$n++]', $query);
}
```

[example on Codepad](http://codepad.org/OxgC18Ms)

Note: If you want to replace `?` only betwen parenthesis, use a lookbehind like this: `preg_replace('~\?(?=[^\(\)]*\))~e', '$array[$n++]', $query);`

Comment: thanks, this one should work...but not sure what I am doing wrong, each ? takes the letter by letter ..i.e. v,a,l,u,e ....1,v,a,l...

Comment: Look at my example on [codepad](http://codepad.org/OxgC18Ms). You array must be like that: `array('value1', 'value2', ...)`. Like in your question. What do you have when you `print_r` your array ?

Comment: my array is as below..but I used foreach to get the value alone and have it a variable..then I have the other sql statement with ? in a variable..now when I try what you gave, it takes letter by letter for each question instead of the whole value. i have a function that gives these two ouputs(array and sql..) and in that i want to replace each ? with the value...for example, i get 4 array as output and I have 4 matching sql, so each thing should ? should be replaced with the value..sorry if i was not clear first time.
Array = (
1 => 'value1',
2 => 'value2',
3 => 'value3',
)

Comment: sorry, [link](http://codepad.org/Aprh4Jlx)..will not give output but i have written comments..hope this is clear

Comment: The variable `profile` contains `value1\nvalue2\n...`. You can do the folowing: `echo $this->replaceWithArray($queryStatement, explode("\n", $profile));`. Join [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3276/discussion-between-pinouchon-and-geej) if you have more questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $query1 =str_replace("?,?,?","'".implode("','",$values1 )."'",$query1);
echo $query2 =str_replace("?,?,?","'".implode("','",$values2 )."'",$query2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This exact sollution can be done like this:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `table2` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`,`column4`,`column5`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

$values1 = array("value1","value2","value3");
$values2 = array("value1","value2","value3","value4","value5");


function insertIntoQuery($query, $values){
    $countval = count($values);
    $replace = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$countval; $i++){
        $replace[] = '?';
    }
    $implode = implode(",", $replace);
    $values = implode("','", $values);
    $query = str_replace($implode, "'".$values."'", $query);
    return $query;
}

echo insertIntoQuery($query1, $values1);
echo "<br />";
echo insertIntoQuery($query2, $values2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ?,?,? within the select statement it is meta-syntactic and MySQL will substitute those variables with real values at run time. This can be dangerous if your format is variable, but if you are using static data MySQL's first guess will always be the correct one if it was aligned correctly to begin with.

According to the Php 5.x manual there is a function call for this array_replace, which oddly enough looks a lot like your example. I'm running Php 5.2 and the server has always just balked at that function call like so:

Fatal error:  Call to undefined function array_replace()

But both CLI and mod_php are post 5.2xx

[root@networktag dom]# php -i | grep -i version
PHP Version => 5.2.10

Now while the example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php says to replace the array this way, until whoever created the programming language interpreter catches up to whoever wrote the manual it doesn't seem to work on a vanilla datacenter installed Linux box running CentOS 5.2 with PhP rpmforge upgrades to 5.2. It really is a moot point since Php 5.x+ support array de-referencing like so:

```
$array_1 = array('Tom','Dick','Harry');
$array_1[1] = "Car 54";
print_r($array_1);
```

outputs:
    Array
    (
         [0] => Tom
         [1] => Car 54
         [2] => Harry
    )

If you need a more fine grain of control on de-referencing or replacing the array values then don't rely on default indexing in the primary array. Create an incremental counter then cast the array index with it such as $array[$i]=array("Foo" => "Bar", "Bar" => "Foo"); where $i is $i++.

...OR... if you are using a newer version of Php you can even reference the sub index from outside the logical boundary with

```
print_r($array[$i])(0);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = implode("','",$array);
INSERT INTO "table1" ('column1', 'column2', 'column3') VALUES ('$foo')
```